# how to change my custom post UI in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

when i click my custom post permalink it's returned my post but it is not in my post template structure.it's return kind of a default UI structure.how do i change the custom post view to my own html post template.please help me

Comment: Create a file name `archive-{custom-post-type-slug}.php` and add your code there!

Comment: Please Can you give some example

Comment: If your Post type name is `gallery`, create file like `archive-gallery.php`

Comment: how to set my clicked post title and content to that template

Comment: how archive-{custom-post-type-slug}.php should be

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates read this, you'll get it

Comment: i got it thanks @hemnath mouli i create a file named single-{custom-post-type-slug}.php